# Поиск и проверка значений SQLite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Помогите найти решение.

Общее описание программы такое - есть CGI веб сервер, человек переходя на сайт вводит данные `VKID` и `UID` , они передаются в `check.py`.

Задача такова: нужно прочесть БД SQLite  найти эту строчку с этими значениями.
  И если `qiwi (из cgi) == qiwi (из бд) & uid(cgi) == uid()`, то вызывается функция 
`checkqiwi(qiwi, uid)`

Подключение БД и получение данных из CGI

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "database.db")

con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cur = con.cursor()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
vkid = form.getvalue("vkid")
uid = form.getvalue("uid")
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаете запрос, передавая значения из переменных и проверяете что вернется

Примерно так:

```
qiwi = ...
uid = ...

has = connect.execute("SELECT 1 FROM FooTable WHERE qiwi=? AND uid=?", (qiwi, uid)).fetchone()
if has:
    checkqiwi(qiwi, uid)
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  F
ile "Web\\cgi-bin\\check.py", line 53, in <module> check_db = checkdb(vkid, uid)  File "Web\\cgi-bin\\check.py", line 39, in checkdb  has = cur.execute
("SELECT 1 FROM database WHERE vkid=?, uid=?",(vkid,uid)).fetchone()  sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`

Что не так?

Comment: Это моя опечатка. Посмотрите ответ, я уже исправил ту опечатку в условии